# I need to partition a huge table and truncate the partition on daily basis

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table tblCallDataStore which has a flow of 2 millions records daily.Daily, I need to delete any record older than 48 hours. If I create a delete job, it runs for more than 13 hours or sometimes more than that. What is the feasible way to partition the table and truncate the partition.
How may I do that?

I have a Receivedate column and I want to do the partition on its basis.

Comment: Table and Index Partitioning is available in every edition of SQL Server 2016 SP1 and later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you will need to bite the one-time bullet and [add partitioning to your table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/create-partitioned-tables-and-indexes?view=sql-server-2017) (hint: base it off the `DATEPART(DAY, ...)` of the timestamp you are keying off of so you can quickly get this as your `@ParitionID` variable later). After that, you can use the [`SWITCH PARTITION`](https://www.cathrinewilhelmsen.net/2015/04/19/table-partitioning-in-sql-server-partition-switching/) statement to move all rows of the specified partition ID to another table. You can then quickly `TRUNCATE` the receiving table since you don't care about the data anymore.

There are a couple of tricky setup steps in this process: Managing the partition IDs themselves, and ensuring the receiving table has an [identical structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms191160(v=sql.105)) (and various other requirements, such as not being able to refer to your partitioned table with foreign keys (umm... ouch)). Once you have the partition ID you want, the code is simple:

```
ALTER TABLE [x] SWITCH PARTITION @PartitionID TO [x_copy]
```

---

I have been meaning to write a stored procedure to automatically maintain the receiving tables, since at work we have just been manually updating both tables in tandem whenever we make a change (e.g. adding a new column or index). To manually do it, basically just copy the table definition and append something to all the entity names (e.g. just put the number 2 on the end).

---

P.S. Maybe you want to use hourly partitioning instead, then you have much more control over the "48 hours" requirement, and also have the flexibility to handle time zones (ugh). You'd just have to be more clever since `DATEPART(HOUR, ...)` obviously won't work directly. Also note that your partition IDs must be defined as a range, so eventually you will end up cycling through them, so keep that in mind.

P.P.S. As noted in the comments by [David Browne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7297700), partitioning was an enterprise-only feature until SQL 2016 SP1.